# Understanding packages and NuGet for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

While I have years of experience with .NET development, I can't say that I've kept up with the most recent version of VS. I don't know of many developers who can simply upgrade to the latest version every time one is released. Google however has made it very problematic to use their APIs when they write their sample code using the latest version of VS because this code will not compile under older versions. I seriously wish they would stop doing that. They should be developing code to run on the older versions and simply leave it up to the developer to upgrade their own code if they want to use the latest version of VS.

In the process of having to migrate their code backward, I came across "packages" for the first time that use the NuGet tool. I have never used NuGet before and it was never installed in my VS environment. At first I found it rather confusing as the NuGet.org site has virtually no documentation as to what the purpose of this tool is, nor how it is really used. But after fumbling around for a few hours, I did manage to get NuGet installed and the Google Drive APIs working.

However, when I went to create a new project, I didn't use the NuGet tool but just added all the references that were in the project that did work. When I went to compile this app though, it complained that it could not find a library or some dependent library.

It was only after I used the NuGet command line and imported the packages did it work. This does raise the question though as to what the NuGet tool does. Clearly, just adding references manually isn't good enough. All my development work up until now has always been just to manually add references and things worked. Why all of a sudden would an app not work when I've added all the references manually? What exactly is NuGet doing that I'm taking into consideration? And finally, what really is the purpose of using NuGet to start with?

Thanks for your insight.